# how to generate the Laplacian most efficiently

Tags: algorithms

I have a cubic lattice $L_1\times L_2 \times L_3$ with the periodic boundary condition.

I have to construct the Laplacian matrix in the sparse format. My matlab code is like this

```
L = 30;
dim = L^3;
COO1 = zeros(2, dim*6);
ss = 0;
for s1 = 0: L-1
    for s2 = 0: L-1
        for s3 = 0: L-1
            ss = ss + 1;
            ind = 1+ s1 + L* s2 + L^2 *s3;
            ind1 = 1+ mod(s1+1,L) + L* s2 + L^2 *s3;
            ind2 = 1+ mod(s1-1,L) + L* s2 + L^2 *s3;
            ind3 = 1+ s1 + L*mod(s2+1,L) + L^2 * s3;
            ind4 = 1+ s1 + L*mod(s2-1,L) + L^2 * s3;
            ind5 = 1+ s1 + L*s2 + L^2 * mod(s3+1, L);
            ind6 = 1+ s1 + L*s2 + L^2 * mod(s3-1, L);
            COO1(1,1+(ss-1)*6: ss*6) = ind;
            COO1(2,1+(ss-1)*6: ss*6) = [ind1, ind2, ind3, ind4, ind5, ind6];
        end
    end
end

Lap = sparse(COO1(1,:),COO1(2,:),-ones(1, dim*6),dim,dim);
```

I do feel that the algorithm is not efficient. Is it possible to improve it?

Comment: The first question to ask is: do you *have* to generate the Laplacian as a sparse matrix? In many contexts you can get away with implementing instead a function `matvec(v)` that, given a vector $v$, computes $Lv$. For instance, you can do this if you are just applying sparse solvers and evaluating residuals.

Comment: The second question is what does "I feel that the algorithm is not efficient" mean? Have you tested it? Do you have evidence that it is not efficient? There is no need to optimize things that turn out to be fast enough.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth  well, it is fast enough for me. But, I just feel the code might be shortened and more compact.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni   Yes, I have to generate the Laplacian as a sparse matrix, and the only action I need is to repeatedly apply the matrix to an arbitrary vector. It is indeed possible to perform this action without generate the Laplacian matrix, but that is not simpler.

Comment: If there is no need to optimize something, then I will point you at the famous quote "premature optimization is the root of all evil": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common trick to simplify the creation and evaluation of a high dimensional discrete Laplacian on simple domains is by taking advantage of its tensor product structure.  The discrete 3D Laplacian on your periodic grid can be written as
$$
D = D_\text{1D} \otimes I \otimes I + I \otimes D_\text{1D} \otimes I + I \otimes I \otimes D_\text{1D},
$$
where $\otimes$ is the Kronecker product and $D_\text{1D}$ is the 1D Laplacian matrix:
$$
D_\text{1D} = \begin{bmatrix}
-2 & 1 & & 1 \\
1 & -2 & 1 & & \\
& \ddots & \ddots \ddots \\
1 & & 1 & -2 
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

In MATLAB code, this is

```
L = 30;
id = speye(L);
Lap1D = spdiags(ones(L, 1) * [1, 1, -2, 1, 1], [1-L, -1:1, L-1], L, L);
Lap = kron(Lap1D, kron(id, id)) + kron(id, kron(Lap1D, id)) + kron(id, kron(id, Lap1D));
```

As requested in the comments, it is simpler and more compact.  At least in Octave on my computer, it is also about 5x faster.

Comment: thanks a lot! It is indeed 5x faster with Matlab on my laptop.